# How to define this component as function instead of class

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ChatHistory extends Component {
  render() {
    const messages = this.props.chatHistory.map((msg, index) => (
      <p key={index}>{msg.data}</p>
    ));

    return (
      <div className="ChatHistory">
        <h2>Chat History</h2>
        {messages}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ChatHistory;
```

As React documentation recommends i would like to migrate this into function, but i'm struggling around line where `map()` function being used

Comment: Struggling _how_ exactly? Give a [mre]. Your component was already stateless, this should not be difficult to migrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming ChatHistory type is something like this:

```
type ChatHistoryType = {
  data: string;
}
```

We can then create the type for the props as shown below:

```
type ChatHistoryProps = {
  chatHistory: ChatHistoryType[]
}
```

With this we can start creating the functional component like this:

```
export default function ChatHistory({ chatHistory }: ChatHistoryProps) {
  return (
    <div className="ChatHistory">
      <h2>Chat History</h2>
      {chatHistory.map((msg, index) => (
        <p key={index}>{msg.data}</p>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is how I will create React Functional Components. I hope this helped you. This is my first time answering a question so apologies if I am not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

here's my suggestion:

```
export const ChatHistory = () => {
  const messages = this.props.chatHistory.map((msg, index) => (
      return (
          <p key={index}>{msg.data}</p>
      )
  ));

  return (
    <div className="ChatHistory">
      <h2>Chat History</h2>
      {messages}
    </div>
  )
}
```

just change the declaration from class to a const that equals an arrow function. Hope this helps!

Comment: Was originally `export default`

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I can help you migrate this class component into a functional component using React hooks. Here's how you can achieve that:

```
import React from "react";

function ChatHistory(props) {
  const messages = props.chatHistory.map((msg, index) => (
    <p key={index}>{msg.data}</p>
  ));

  return (
    <div className="ChatHistory">
      <h2>Chat History</h2>
      {messages}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ChatHistory;
```

In this functional component version, we're using the useState hook for managing component state, and the map function usage remains the same as it was in the class component. The major change is the syntax and the removal of the Component class inheritance.